# Prolog - predicate to sort and merge list

Tags: prolog

Hi I am trying to write a predicate that sorts first list low to high and second list high to low, then puts the heads of each list in to a new list.

Comment: `mix([], [], X)` says if you mix the emtpy list (`[]`) with the empty list (`[]`)  you get anything you want (`X`). That doesn't seem logical, does it? `mix([], X, X)` seems logical. As would, `mix(X, [], X)` which you don't have. `mix([H1|T1], [H2|T2], [H1|X]) :- mix(T1, T2, [H2|X]).` I think just needs to be `mix([H1|T1], [H2|T2], [H1,H2|T]) :- mix(T1, T2, T)` right? The common name for this is `zip` rather than `mix`.

Answer (score 0):

Here the code for the `mix/3` predicate:

```
mix([],[],[]).
mix([],[H1|T1],[H1|T2]):-
    mix([],T1,T2).
mix([H1|T1],[],[H1|T2]):-
    mix(T1,[],T2).
mix([H1|T1],[H2|T2],[H1,H2|T3]) :-
   mix(T1,T2,T3).
```

This one works also with input list with different length.